# How to split data fields and logic based on authorization?

Tags: api, security, authorization, graphql

For example I have `posts` endpoint, `post` have `title`, `description`, `status`. When I show post to user I want to limit `post` fields to `title` and `description`. But when I show `post` to admin I want to send all fields of `post`, so how it spit ? I can create two post models, for user which consist of `title` and `description`, for admin with all fields, look what is role of the user and decide which model to chose. Or create rule on every model and role, which look at role and cut data by role. I use graphql and can fetch only fields thats I need, but it isn't security because, user can modify request and gat all data. How resolve this problem ?

Thank You !

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't make two models, but limit the access of a user to only `title` and `description` on server side.

On client side I would only ask for `status` additionally if the user is admin. (To make this elegant, see [fragments](http://graphql.org/learn/queries/#fragments).)

You need to identify on server side if someone is admin or normal user, otherwise no API can save you from modified requests.